# Passing double quotes in JavaScript function parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm have trouble with the following html

```
<span onClick="alert('hi&#34 more stuff')">Works</span><br/>
<span onClick='alert("Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.")'>Works long text</span>
<br />
<span onClick='alert("Far far &#34 away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.")'> Doesn't work long text</span>
```

My problem is that in the third onclick handler, I'm getting an unterminated string error in the browser.  In the real program, the parameter strings are being generated client side, so all encoding has to happen there.

In the example that does work, I've tried both `&#34;` and `&quot;` and works in the last example.  But they do work in the first example

There is a working sample at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/9d43U/1/

Comment: just use `\"` instead

Comment: If you kept your JS out of your HTML you'd be able to avoid the issue of encoding a quote within a JS string within an HTML attribute.

Comment: `span` elements are not interactive, they won't appear in the default focus order, you should seriously consider using `<button>` elements instead.

Comment: @Quentin, while that's true, an alternative is to add `role="button"`, and `tabindex="0"` to the span. It makes for a button that's much easier to style cross-browser.

Answer (score 10):

To use a `"` in a JavaScript `"` delimited string, use `\"`.

To use a `"` in an HTML `"` delimited attribute value, use `&quot;`.

Combine them if needed: `\&quot;`

---

Alternatively, stop using intrinsic event attributes, write [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and bind your event handlers [programatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: I vote for the unobtrusive JavaScript suggestion, though in lieu of that, `\&quot;` is a safer option than `\"` if you are operating inside HTML attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Just escape it with a backslash `\"`.

Comment: While this should work, I'm downvoting you to make the point that it's still not valid HTML and is subject to accidental breakage should the quotes around the attribute change. Ideally you'd properly HTML encode the double quote character.

Comment: @zzzzBov I agree with the potential breakage, but how is it not valid HTML?

Comment: @zzzzBov I don't get your point here. First of all, having `\"` inside JavaScript string has nothing to do with HTML validity. Next, if you care about quotes around the attribute value, bare in mind, it will affect the quotes around the JS function argument as well, hence the best thing is binding events dynamically and not inline.

Comment: @VisioN, it is not valid HTML because I'm completely wrong and should apologize. Sorry about that. Somehow I'd gotten it in my head that all `"` values needed to be escaped to `&quot;` to be valid, but I'm wrong about that one. My point on accidental breakage still stands, but I'll remove the downvote as soon as I'm able.

Comment: @zzzzBov Accepted `:)` Otherwise, yeah, your concern about possible problems this method leads to is completely correct and it was worth to note it to make the answer more complete. However proposing more stable solution *might* go beyond the real question.

Answer (score -3):

first you should write html like:

```
attribute="property"
```

so if you write:

```
onclick="alert('what you want here with encoded content it will work')"
```

see your updated fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/darkyndy/9d43U/5/