# Pass HTML as a parameter to a javascript function from c# WCF

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf

I'm creating my HTML code from WCF (c#), when creating the button action I'm passing several parameters one of them will be an HTML code. The issue that I'm facing when the HTML is containing a double quote " the HTML page thinks that the parameters finish there.

I tried to use Encoded html but when sending it from WCF to HTML it decode it automatically

for example javascript

```
function generateDocumentMenu(screenName,mainItemId,taskId,subItem, documentMenu) 
{
    createPopup(decodeURI(documentMenu) ,"","20%","20%","60%","60%");
}
```

C#

```
 screen.Append("<a href='#' id='documentGeneration' class='button popup-toolbar-button document-generation' onclick='generateDocumentMenu(\"" + screenName + "\",\"" 
 + mainItemId.ToString() + "\",\"" + taskId.ToString() + "\",\"" + subItem + "\", \""+documentMenu +"\");'>");
```

The issue that i'm facing is with documentMenu for example:

```
generateDocumentMenu("user","123","123","user","<div onclick='fn("param");'>aze</div>")
```

in this example the quotes surrounding param will make a problem i thought about encoding documentMenu variable but it didn't work for me

Comment: Without seeing your code it is impossible to know what is wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing double quotes in JavaScript function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167712/passing-double-quotes-in-javascript-function-parameter)

Comment: @NineBerry I tried to use Encoded html but when sending it from WCF to HTML it decode it automatically

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya code sample posted

Answer (score 0):

Try to scape the literal quotes inserting backslash before

```
"<div onclick='fn(\"param\");'>aze</div>")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your param is a variable, you could write your js as follows:

```
"<div onclick=\"fn('" + param + "');\">aze</div>"
```